# Why can't we freely make and discharge assumptions in system $K$?

Tags: logic, proof-writing, modal-logic

The following comes from Blackburn's text on Modal Logic:

> **Remark 1.41** Warning: there is a pitfall that is very easy to fall into if you are used
> to working with natural deduction systems: we cannot freely make and discharge
> assumptions in the Hilbert system **K**. The following ‘proof’ shows what can go
> wrong if we do:
>
> 1. $p$ (assumption)
> 2. $\square p$ (generalisation: 1)
> 3. $p\to\square p$ (discharge assumption)
>
> So we have ‘proved’ $p\to\square p$! This is obviously wrong: this formula is not valid,
> hence it is not K-provable. And it should be clear where we have gone wrong:
> we cannot use assumptions as input to generalization, for, as we have already remarked, this rule does not preserve satisfiability. Generalization is there to enable
> us to generate new validities from old. It is not a local rule of inference.

I'm not able to understand what the problem really is! I know that  $p\to\square p$ is not valid, so something is definitely wrong. Could someone please explain this in detail?

Which part is incorrect (of the three steps above)? I think it's okay to make the assumption $p$. The problem **probably lies in the second part**, but I'm not sure why we cannot use generalization/necessitation on assumptions (even though the author has explained it - I do not get it).

It'd be very helpful if someone could help me understand this better!

Comment: Step 2: generalization (modal as well as UG) do not applies to assumptions but only to theorems. Example: from assumption $x=0$ we cannot safely derive $\forall x (x=0)$. Instead, we can start from logical axiom $x=x$ to derive $\forall x (x=x)$.

Comment: The restriction applies to Gen rule (and Necessitation). With other rules, you can discharge assumptions: $A \vdash A \lor B$. Thus, applying $\to$-intro (that discharges) we conclude with: $\vdash A \to (A \lor B)$.

Comment: See [Modal Logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-modal/#WhaModLog): The most familiar logics in the modal family are constructed from a weak logic called $\mathsf K$. It results from adding the following to the principles of propositional logic: **Necessitation Rule**:   If $A$ is a theorem of $\mathsf K$, then so is $\square A$. **Distribution Axiom**: $□(A→B)→(□A→□B)$. These rules must be stated in your textbook...

Comment: Thanks a lot, that makes sense!

Comment: You are welcome :-) The reason for the restriction are exactly to avoid deriving unsound formulas, like $p \to \square p$ and $P(x) \to \forall x P(x)$.